# Trying to iterate through rows, and concatenate the cells at the end of the row with =TEXT formatting, and I am getting a 1004 error.

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a sheet and trying to concatenate the cells through VBA, however I have to have the output come out in a very specific way, because each item has to be in a specific position in the string. I have managed to get this function to give me the desired results in excel:

```
'=CONCATENATE(RC8,RC17,TEXT(RC4,"0000000000000  "), [RC9," ",TEXT(RC7,"00000"),"      ",TEXT(MID(RC3,7,9),"00000000 "),"FB4852","    ","01","    ",TEXT(RC2,"0000000000000   "))
```

However, when I slapped this into some code (and had to add a ton of extra quotation marks to get it to compile) to add this function to the last cell of a row, and concatenate all of the selected data in that row, it started giving me 1004 errors. I have attached my sub below, any help that y'all can provide this lost new VBA coder would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

```
    Sub gpFormat()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet
lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 18), sh.Cells(lastRow, 18)).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC8,RC17,TEXT(RC4,""0000000000000  ""), [RC9,"" "",TEXT(RC7,""00000""),""      "",TEXT(MID(RC3,7,9),""00000000 ""),""FB4852"",""    "",""01"",""    "",TEXT(RC2,""0000000000000   ""))"""
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

You have two extra "" at the end of the string, just delete then

```
Sub gpFormat()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet
lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 18), sh.Cells(lastRow, 18)).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC8,RC17,TEXT(RC4,""0000000000000  ""),RC9,"" "",TEXT(RC7,""00000""),""      "",TEXT(MID(RC3,7,9),""00000000 ""),""FB4852"",""    "",""01"",""    "",TEXT(RC2,""0000000000000   ""))"

End Sub
```

good luck

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

it seems thant you made a typo

try to replace the **[** RC9," ",  to **(** RC9," ",

good luck

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Typo was corrected, however the 1004 reject is still getting thrown.